# GCM not working with proguard enabled

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-proguard

I am developing an app that uses GCM to receive push notifications from server. It works fine when proguard is disable ( minify false ), but when I make a release build with minify enabled, it doesn't receive pushes anymore.
I added some rules to my proguard-rules.pro, but still they don't change anything.
This is my proguard-rules.pro

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /Users/polbins/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Retrofit 2
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-dontwarn okio.**

# SL4J for Android
-dontwarn javax.mail.**
-dontwarn javax.naming.Context
-dontwarn javax.naming.InitialContext

# View Pager Indicator
-dontwarn com.viewpagerindicator.**

# Bubbl Models
-keep class tech.bubbl.sdk.rest.models.** { *; }

# Needed to keep generic types and @Key annotations accessed via reflection

-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault

-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}

# Needed by google-http-client-android when linking against an older platform version

-dontwarn com.google.api.client.extensions.android.**

# Needed by google-api-client-android when linking against an older platform version

-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.**

# Needed by google-play-services when linking against an older platform version

-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontnote com.google.android.gms.**

# com.google.client.util.IOUtils references java.nio.file.Files when on Java 7+
-dontnote java.nio.file.Files, java.nio.file.Path

# Suppress notes on LicensingServices
-dontnote **.ILicensingService

# Suppress warnings on sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontnote sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
```

Did I miss any rules? Or what else might be causing this?

Comment: Does it give you any exceptions?

Comment: No, I just don't receive the pushes.

Comment: If you're using Android Studio, you may want to check this [Proguard guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) to know how you should enable shrinking and how to specify what code and resources to keep or discard during the build. See if you've missed some of the given notes or rules. Also, as noted in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), to use ProGuard with Android Studio, you must enable the ProGuard setting in your `build.gradle buildTypes`.

Comment: You may also check this [GitHub post](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/165) and see if it will help you.

Comment: Not much of help. I think I need some specific rules for GCM library, but those which I found don't work,

Comment: This is odd. I'm fairly sure there isn't any *specific* rules that is needed for GCM (or FCM) to work with proguard. Are you positive that you're using the corresponding registration token when sending the message(s)?